# how to change the date format taken from the database in data table

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

Im creating Laravel Project and have a data table that show some data, one of the data is date, the format show in data table is equal with date data in database (YYYY-MM-DD). I want to show it in format **`04 Feb 2020`** or **`04-02-2020`**.
here is my View code

```
var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('home.index') }}",

            columns: [{
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'title',
                    name: 'title',
                    orderable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'content',
                    name: 'content',
                    orderable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'progress',
                    name: 'progress'
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    name: 'status'
                },
                {
                    data: 'finish_date',
                    name: 'finish_date'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ]
        });
```

here is my controller

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {

                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Edit"  class=" edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editProduct"><span class="fas fa-pen"></span></a>';

                    $btn = $btn . ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteProduct"><span class="fas fa-trash"></span></a>';

                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('index');
```

can I change the date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize `yajra-datatables` column by **[addColumn()](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column)** method :

```php
return Datatables::of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
        $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Edit"  class=" edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editProduct"><span class="fas fa-pen"></span></a>';
        $btn = $btn . ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteProduct"><span class="fas fa-trash"></span></a>';
        return $btn;
    })
    ->addColumn('finish_date', function($row)
      {
         $date = date("d F Y", strtotime($row->finish_date));
         return $date;
      })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
}
```